# JS Shorthand for Applying a Function to Input.value

Tags: javascript

I have defined a function `ParseInput(Input)` for cleaning up user's input.  The function returns the cleaned-up input.
May I ask if there is any vanilla javascript shorthand for:

```
document.getElementById(ElementID).value = ParseInput(document.getElementById(ElementID).value))
```

Many thanks!

Comment: No, there is not. But you could easily implement a helper function for that.

Comment: @str I was thinking if there is something similar to the "+=" operator that I am not aware of.  Then I guess I will add a function.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "shorthand." The code is a bit repetitive maybe because you retrieve the same element twice.

You could do:

```js
let element = document.getElementById(ElementID);
element.value = ParseInput(element.value);
```

Either way you had a superfluous closing parenthesis at the end of your code.